# Execute method in each object in list in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a list of objects, and I want to execute a method in each object in parallel. The method modifies the attributes of the objects. For example:

```python
class Object:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def aplus(self):
        self.a += 1

object_list = [Object(1), Object(2), Object(3)]

# I want to execute this in parallel
for i in range(len(object_list)):
    object_list[i].aplus()
```

I tried the following:

```python
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
res = executor.map([obj.aplus for obj in object_list])
```

Which does not work, leaving the objects unaltered. I assume it's because the objects can only be copied, and not accessed, with multiprocessing. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Supposedly the objects are very big, so it would be preferable to avoid copying them to each process. The methods are also supposedly very CPU intensive, so multiple processes rather than threads should be used. Within these conditions, I believe there is no solution, as multiprocessing cannot share memory and threads cannot use multiple CPUs. I would like to be shown wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example using `Pool.map`:

```
import multiprocessing

class Object:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def aplus(self):
        self.a += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)

def worker(obj):
    obj.aplus()
    return obj

if __name__ == "__main__":
    object_list = [Object(1), Object(2), Object(3)]

    try:
        processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    except NotImplementedError:
        processes = 2

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes)
    modified_object_list = pool.map(worker, object_list)

    for obj in modified_object_list:
        print(obj)
```

Prints:

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I arrived to similar solutions, but I would like to avoid copying the objects as I assume they are big.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer, using `threading`:

```
from threading import Thread

class Object:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def aplus(self):
        self.a += 1

object_list = [Object(1), Object(2), Object(3)]

# A list containing all threads we will create
threads = []

# Create a thread for every objects
for obj in object_list:
    thread = Thread(target=obj.aplus)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

# Wait for all threads to finish before continuing
for thread in threads:
    thread.join();

# prints results
for obj in object_list:
    print(obj.a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The tasks inside the object are CPU intensive, and according to what I read somewhere else (https://medium.com/@bfortuner/python-multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-73072ce5600b) multiprocessing is better than multithread in those cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the GIL, Python's multithreading can only use one core. Only multiprocessing allows Python to use more cores, at the cost of slower creation (a process being much heavier than a thread) or harder memory sharing. In this case, you might want to go for Rafael's answer. Another way could be to go for a C++ implementation (having used C++ multithreading myself, I can tell you it works exactly the same way as my answer, and can use multiple cores).

Answer (score 1):

> I assume it's because the objects can only be copied, and not
>   accessed, with multiprocessing.

This is exactly right, and is half the answer. Because the processes are isolated they each have their own copy of the `object_list`. One solution here is to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` (the threads all share the same `object_list`).

The syntax to use it is a bit different from what you are trying to use, but this works as intended:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
res = executor.map(Object.aplus, object_list)
```

If you really want to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` then you'll need to get the data back from the processes somehow. The easiest way is to use functions which return values:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


class Object:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def aplus(self):
        self.a += 1
        return self.a


if __name__ == '__main__':

    object_list = [Object(1), Object(2), Object(3)]

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    for result in executor.map(Object.aplus, object_list):
        print("I got: " + str(result))
```

You can even have the function you are `map`ing return `self`, and put those returned objects back into your `object_list` at then end. So the full multiprocessing solution would look like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


class Object:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def aplus(self):
        self.a += 1
        return self


if __name__ == '__main__':

    object_list = [Object(1), Object(2), Object(3)]

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    object_list = list(executor.map(Object.aplus, object_list))
```